# Weak convergence in $W^{1,2}$ implies strong convergence under extra condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a smooth bounded domain. Let $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(U)$ such that it weakly converges to zero: $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Also assume that for any bounded sequence of test functions

$$(\phi_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset W^{1,2}_0(U)$$

we have the convergence

$$\int_U \nabla u_n(x) \cdot \nabla \phi_n(x) dx \to 0$$

Can I conclude that $\nabla u_n \to 0$ in $L^2(U)$? Clearly I cannot take that test function $\phi_n = u_n$ because of the zero boundary condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $d \ge 2$. Let $K \subset H^1(U)$ be the subspace of weakly harmonic functions, i.e., all $u$ satisfying
$$
\int_U\nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm d x = 0
$$
for all $\varphi \in H_0^1(U)$. Then, $K$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Then, any orthonormal sequence $(u_n)$ satisfies your assertions but does not converge strongly to zero.

[I believe that your assertion is true in case $d = 1$, since the dimension of $K$ is $2$ in this case.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please tell how do you know the dimension of $K$? Specifically that when $d=2$ it is $2$-dimensional? Or any reference would be much appreciated. I found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30678/dimension-of-the-space-of-harmonic-functions-on-the-unit-ball) post, which seems to suggest that the dimension is $\infty$.

Comment: I think $K$ is 2-dimensional for $d=1$ and infinite-dimensional for $d\ge 2$.

Comment: @user1081759: There was a typo in the last paragraph, it should read "$d = 1$" there.